# New line in Python for loop with sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to create a small function that prints successive lines from a database I'm working with. What I currently have written does that quite well, except it's all a blocky mess and "\n" is interpreted literally rather than actually creating a new line.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
database = conn.cursor()

def textfromDB(text):
    for row in database.execute("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 = ?", [text]):
        print row
        print "\n"
```

Comment: I believe what you want is to use print without the "\n".

Comment: Then we need a (mockup) input and desired output.

Comment: @CannedSpinach the output also depends on the type of the row you are printing. If it's a tuple, then in Python REPL it may be printed as long lines with '\n' instead of text with the real line breaks. If you will print just one text value from each row (say, row[0]) rather than a tuple, then it will look like nice

Comment: @vrs thanks, that does the trick perfectly!

Comment: In general, if you have a list, tuple or dictionary data structure that is printed in a badly to read way, you should try `pprint.pprint()` to get a better formatted output.

Comment: @CannedSpinach Glad it helped! I summed up my comments as an answer below. It's expanded with some details about printing tuples. Please, consider accepting/upvoting it, if you think I solved you problem. It may help other people finding solution for the same kind of problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print a row inside a `for` loop for sqlite queries, in fact, you print a tuple. So the mess with newline characters you are talking about is the question of tuples representation using `print`. If what you need is to change sparse format with literally interpreted  `\n`'s to normal text, then you have to convert your tuple to a string. You can achieve that by changing `print row` by this command:

```
print(', '.join(map(str, row)))
```

What it's doing is joining all elements of a tuple into one string. `map` function ensures that non-string items (like `int`s) of the tuple converted to string, before `join` function can concatenate them. If there are no non-`str` items in your tuples, then you can omit `map` function.

Also, as @timgeb pointed out in comments, you may use pretty print module `pprint`. It doesn't change `\n`s to actual line breaks, but can print tuples with nice indentation and other formatting features. It may be quite helpful, when debugging a program that does something with longish tuples, lists, sets or dicts. In your case, you'd need to import pprint first:

```
from pprint import pprint
```

And then use `pprint(row)` instead of `print row`.  See pprint's [docs](https://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) for more details.